# Stopwatch program

Tags: python-3.x, stopwatch

I need to make a stop watch program, I need Start, Stop, Lap, Reset and Quit functions. The program needs print elapsed times whenever the Stop or Lap key is pressed. When the user chooses to quit the program should write a log file containing all the timing data (event and time) acquired during the session in human readable format.

```
import os
import time

log = ' '

def cls():
os.system('cls')

def logFile(text):
    logtime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )
    f = open('log.txt','w')
    f.write('Local current time :', logtime, '\n')
    f.write(text, '\n\n')
    f.close()

def stopWatch():
    import time
    p = 50
    a = 0
    hours = 0
    while a < 1:
    cls()
    for minutes in range(0, 60):
        cls()
        for seconds in range(0, 60):
            time.sleep(1)
            cls()
            p +=1
            print ('Your time is: ', hours, ":" , minutes, ":" , seconds)
            print ('               H   M   S')
            if p == 50:
                break
    hours += 1

stopWatch()
```

I have it ticking the time, however they way I have it wont allow me to stop or lap or take any input. I worked to a few hours to find a way to do it but no luck. Any Ideas on how im going to get the functions working?

Comment: I would go at this a completely different way. I would have a base time set with `time.time()` that is set every time you hit the `start()` button. A lap would then just be `time.time() - base_time`.

Comment: http://ideone.com/RR9mSL

Comment: That is perfect, Thank you. now i just have to format the times in how i did it before.